# Phalcon\Mvc\Model::find() failes with condition "column value IN (list)"

Tags: php, model, phalcon

Following code throws exception "Invalid SQL expression type 'list'":

```
$condition = 'id IN(1,2,4)';
Model::find($condition);
```

I can't believe that phalcon does not support this.
What is the correct way to setup this rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To setup this rule, we should simply setup ids list as key => value:

```
$ids = [1,2,3];
Model::find(['id' => $ids]);
```

Hope this would be helpful for somebody.

UPD: this will NOT work, numbers should be not array, but string:

```
Model::find('id IN (1,2,3,4)');
```

There was a bug with such construction, but it was fixed in 0.8.0 version.